# How can I reduce an 8" duct to 4" in a short distance?

Tags: kitchens

I currently have my kitchen cabinet that a Trades-Wind vent motor is being placed inside.  The opening is 8" for the vent.  My cabinet is not tall enough to allow for ducting to go from the 8" to a 6" to a 4" (the 4" is the diameter of the piping that is up in the ceiling and going outside) so that I don't see the piping coming out from my cabinet.  Is there some way to cut down on the total height of the piping so that the 8" vent can match to the 4" vent and not be seen when standing in the another room?  My cabinets do not come all the way to the ceilings.

Comment: A picture would be helpful, here.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the hardware and space you're dealing with. Chances are there's an easy solution, even if it means fabricating a reducer to suit.

Comment: Make a reducing cone, a drawing exercise long liked by engineering drawing lecturers...